# Como pudiera enviar los objetos desestructurados de req.query al objeto de un find() de mongo para filtrar

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Estoy tratando de hacer un buscador en el backend de mi aplicación con express, quiero filtrar desde la base de datos por username, por teléfono ,etc, pero necesito seleccionar de la desestructuración de req.query los objetos para llevarlos al filtro del método find() de mongodb, Aquí adjunto el código, agradeceria una ayuda con alguna idea , perdonen mi poco conocimiento quizás lo que pregunto es básico que deba conocerlo estoy comenzando ténganme paciencia.

```
export const searchUserDb = async (req,res) => {

    const { 
        username,
        email,
        phone,
        date,
        createdAt,
        updatedAt
    } = req.query        
       
     const  selector = () => {

         if (username) return username

     }
        const controlSearch = async () => {   

            const SearchDate = await Users.find({})
            res.status(200).json(SearchDate)
            console.log(SearchDate)            
        } 
        controlSearch()  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mil gracias a la comunidad , pude resolver la interrogante y era bien sencillo , perdonen mi torpeza , aquí dejo  el código con mi solucion por si otro colega le sucede :

```
// Controlador para hacer filtraje de User por cualquier campo 
export const searchUserDb = async (req,res) => {

    const { 
        username,
        email,
        phone,
        date,
        createdAt,
        updatedAt
    } = req.query  

    const filter = req.query 
    const SearchDate = await Users.find(filter) 
    res.status(200).json(SearchDate)
}
```